# Rspec - Random spec pass or fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

On Rails 5.2.2 I am using **RSpec** and **Capybara**

I have some random specs that are failing when launched together with the suite. I beleive it depends in which order they are runing...
(They ALL pass individually, though)

I do, which works or not...

```
bin/rails db:drop db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
spring stop
```

I am also using **DatabaseCleaner**, but I am not sure it's working well.

I call the file in **rail_helper.rb**

```
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'support/factory_bot'
require 'support/database_cleaner'
require 'devise'

Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |file| require file }

def login_as(user)
  visit "/users/sign_in"
  fill_in "user[email]", with: user.email
  fill_in "user[password]", with: "password"
  click_on 'login'
end


CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.root              = Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures')
  config.cache_only        = true
  config.enable_processing = false
  config.base_path         = "/"
end


RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.block_unknown_urls
end
```

**support/database_cleaner.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.append_after :each do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    CarrierWave.clean_cached_files!(0)
  end

end
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
 require "capybara/rspec"

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = 'tmp/rspec_examples.txt'
  config.order = :random
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups 

  config.after(:all) do
    if Rails.env.test? 
      FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir["#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads"])
    end 
  end
end
```

Is there anything suspect?

Help would be much appreciated

## WHOLE UPDATE AND CLEANING

- So I removed all from **DatabaseCleaner**
- I changed `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` (it was set to false)
- I ran  `rspec --seed 30300 --bisect` and got the result below

  ```
  Bisect started using options: "--seed 30300"
  Running suite to find failures... (11.63 seconds)
  Starting bisect with 13 failing examples and 54 non-failing examples.
  Checking that failure(s) are order-dependent... failure appears to be order-dependent
  Round 1: bisecting over non-failing examples 1-54 .. ignoring examples 28-54 (12.05 seconds)
  Round 2: bisecting over non-failing examples 1-27 . ignoring examples 1-14 (3.04 seconds)
  Round 3: bisecting over non-failing examples 15-27 . ignoring examples 15-21 (2.88 seconds)
  Round 4: bisecting over non-failing examples 22-27 .. ignoring examples 25-27 (4.86 seconds)
  Round 5: bisecting over non-failing examples 22-24 . ignoring examples 22-23 (2.71 seconds)
  Bisect complete! Reduced necessary non-failing examples from 54 to 1 in 27.66 seconds.
  The minimal reproduction command is:
    rspec './spec/models/dashboard_spec.rb[1:1:1,1:2:1,1:3:1,1:4:1,1:6:1,1:7:1,1:8:1,1:9:1,1:10:1,1:11:1,1:12:1,1

  :14:1,1:15:1]' './spec/models/orders_spec.rb[1:1:1]' --seed 30300
  ```

  The model I am testing:

  ```
  class Dashboard 

   attr_reader :min_date, :max_date

   def initialize(params)
      params ||= {}
      @min_date = parsed_date(params[:min_date],Time.now.beginning_of_month.to_date.to_s)
      @max_date   = parsed_date(params[:max_date], (Date.today + 1).to_s)
   end

   def users_registration_by_week
      User.group_by_week(:created_at, range: (@min_date..@max_date),time_zone: "Paris", week_start: :mon).count
  end

  def users_registration_by_week
      User.group_by_week(:created_at, range: (@min_date..@max_date),time_zone: "Paris", week_start: :mon).count
  end

   def articles_added_by_week
     Article.group_by_week(:created_at, range: (@min_date..@max_date),time_zone: "Paris", week_start: :mon).count
  end

   def articles_counts
     Article.count
   end
  end
  ```

> all the failure in dashboard are similare so iam just showing one

```
 1) Dashboard#users_registration_by_week returns the total number of user by week
     Failure/Error: expect(res.values.last).to eq(2)

       expected: 2
            got: 5

   (compared using ==)
```

This a part of the dashboard_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Dashboard, type: :model do
    let(:date_from) { 5.days.ago.to_date }
  let(:date_to)   { Date.tomorrow }

  subject { Dashboard.new(date_from: @date_from, date_to: @date_to) }

    describe "#users_registration_by_week" do 
        it "returns the total number of users by week" do
            create(:user, created_at: 2.weeks.ago)
            create(:user, created_at: 2.day.ago )
            create(:user, created_at: 1.day.ago)

            res = subject.users_registration_by_week

            expect(res.values.last).to eq(2)
        end
    end

     describe "#users_registration_by_month" do 
        it "returns the total number of user by month" do
            create(:user, created_at: 2.day.ago)
            create(:user, created_at: 1.day.ago)

            res = subject.users_registration_by_month

            expect(res.values.last).to eq(2)
        end
    end


describe "#articles_counts" do 
        it "returns the total number of article" do
            create(:article, sizes_attributes: [size_name: "L", quantity: 3, created_at: 3.months.ago])
            create(:article, sizes_attributes: [size_name: "L", quantity: 3, created_at: 1.day.ago])
            create(:article, sizes_attributes: [size_name: "L", quantity: 3, created_at: 1.day.ago])

            res = subject.articles_counts
            expect(res).to eq(3)
        end
    end

    describe "#articles_added_by_week" do 
        it "returns the total number of article" do
            create(:article, created_at: 2.weeks.ago ,sizes_attributes: [size_name: "L", quantity: 3, created_at: 2.weeks.ago])
            create(:article, created_at: 2.day.ago ,sizes_attributes: [size_name: "L", quantity: 3, created_at: 2.day.ago])
            create(:article, created_at: 1.day.ago ,sizes_attributes: [size_name: "L", quantity: 3, created_at: 1.day.ago])

            res = subject.articles_added_by_week

            expect(res.values.last).to eq(2)
        end
    end
end
```

models/order_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'


 RSpec.describe Order, type: :model do

    fixtures :articles, :users, :sizes

        before(:each) do 
            @shirt  = articles(:blue_shirt)
            @small  = sizes(:small_blue_shirt)
            @large  = sizes(:large_blue_shirt)
            @john = users(:john)
            @token  = 12345678
            @current_cart ||= ShoppingCart.new(token: @token)
            @order  = Order.create(user_id: @john.id, token: @token, status: "pending", sub_total: 80)
         end

    describe "#count_articles" do 
        it "counts the numbers of similar articles" do 
            order_items_1 = OrderItem.create(order_id: @order.id, article_id: @shirt.id , quantity: 2, size_id: @small.id, price: 20)
            order_items_2 = OrderItem.create(order_id: @order.id, article_id: @shirt.id , quantity: 3, size_id: @large.id, price: 20)

            expect(@order.count_articles).to eq 5
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Using rspec's [bisect](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/bisect) capabilities might help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: updated my answer with the result

Comment: From the output I cannot see whether the order_spec is the first to run but I assume it is. I therefore also think that the fixtures are somehow the problem. Could you try to comment out the fixtures briefly and then run the minimal reproduction set printed out by bisect. The orders spec will fail naturally but if the others pass then, you know where the problem lies. If it is the fixtures, if at all feasible, I wouldn't bother trying to fix the problem but rather replace all fixtures by factories.

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 5.1+ DatabaseCleaner is no longer necessary (for most situations) because Rails was updated to safely share a database connection between the AUT thread(s) and the test thread.  Remove all references to DatabaseCleaner from your app and set `use_transactional_fixtures` back to true.  Not only will it more correctly isolate your tests from each other but it should provide a small speedup since data is never actually committed to the DB.

Also, you really should be moving off using capybara-webkit (pretty much obsolete at this point in time) onto selenium with headless chrome or one of the newer direct to Chrome using CDP drivers like [apparition](https://github.com/twalpole/apparition), etc.

Note: you can use the `--seed` option to rspec to specify the seed used during a failing run and the `--bisect` option to have RSpec figure out which test run before causes the failure to happen. That can help narrow down which code is creating extra data in the DB.

Comment: I removed all from DatabaseCleaner but it still failing, also ran `spring stop`

Comment: @user11025649 Did you change your `use_transactional_fixtures` from false to true?

Comment: @user11025649 Then add the test code and exact error you're getting to your question.  Assuming you have fully removed database_cleaner (remove the gem from your Gemfile to ensure you have) from your project and configured for transactional testing there should be no way for DB pollution between tests - and hence no order dependence (Also make sure you've cleared the test DB in case you had anything left in there from previously)

Comment: shall I clean all manually in `before(:each)` or` after(:each)` ?

Comment: @user11025649 No -- just empty it out once -- when you're on transactional testing nothing will ever actually get committed/written to the DB

Comment: this  should do the job `bin/rails db:drop db:create db:migrate  RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: I edited my question with a piece of code and there error

Comment: @user11025649 That test has nothing to do with Capybara - it's not actually running the app.  If that's failing you probably have code elsewhere setting `use_transactional_fixture` (or possibly `use_transactional_tests`) to false -- try searching your code for `use_transactional` . -- or possibly you have some `before(:all)`  blocks somwhere adding data to the DB (bad practice)

Comment: I searched in the whole app for `use_transactional `I only have `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`in the **rail_helper.rb**, now  test don' t pass individually anymore.... unless sring stop and bin/rails db:drop db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

Comment: Added info in my answer about using `seed` and `bisect` to figure out what the order dependence is.  If tests don't pass individually anymore look at the test DB after a run -- if there's any data in any of the tables you have code creating records outside the transactions which you shouldn't be doing (look for any before(:all)/before(:suite) blocks that are creating records)

Comment: `RSpec.feature` is just an alias for `RSpec.describe` with some extra metadata set -- so if that's changed passing of tests then it's likely by doing that you're no longer actually using a JS capable driver for some tests.  The bisect output shows you the minimum tests that need to be run to cause the failure which gives you where to look for data being added to the DB outside the transaction.  Did you find any `before(:all)/before(:suite)` blocks that create records, specifically in dashboard_spec.rb right at the beginning?

Comment: I have some `before(:each)`in the controller spec

Comment: `before(:each)` wouldn't cause this - you have something run at the beginning of dashboard_spec.rb (possibly required) that is creating permanent records in the DB -- without seeing the file it's impossible to say what.

Comment: @marie Nothing there, you might as well add the beginning of orders_spec too since it's the only thing left. Also, you're 100% sure the test DB is empty when you start running the tests?

Comment: just added order_spec

Comment: Yes I drop the db like this it is correct?? `bin/rails db:drop db:create db:migrate  RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: UH -- why are you mixing fixtures and factory_bot?  Comment out the fixtures line in orders_spec and see if all the dashboard tests pass

Comment: aww... could this be the problem?

Comment: I am using fixtures in some feature test too, I though it was possible to use fixtures and factories... well I already saw this in some projects...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `config.use_tranactional_fixtures = true`. Your errors are going to be data-dependent, so clearing the DB between examples should help you. It's a [misleading name](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions).

Comment: isn't it better to use DatabaseCleaner than to manually clean in each all spec?